# Dúvida na procura de sub string, dentro uma string

Tags: c, string

Fiz tudo o que a questão pediu só que estou levando 70 % de erro.

[Link da questão](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2651)

O meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char nome[10000], zelda[6] = "zelda", *ponteiro;
   ponteiro = NULL;
   int i;
   getchar();
   scanf("%[^\n]", nome);
   for(i=0;i<strlen(nome);i++)
   {
      nome[i]=tolower(nome[i]);  //convertendo tudo para minusculo
   }
   ponteiro = strstr(nome, zelda);
   if(ponteiro)
   {
      printf("Link Bolado\n");
      ponteiro = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Link Tranquilo\n");
      ponteiro = NULL;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Pedro "(...) o problema esteja sendo bem claro quando especifica que a string a ser validada é "zelda". Strings como "zEldA", "Zelda", etc são inválidas (...)"  Será ? O um exemplo de uma string bolada nas saídas exemplificadas é "Zeldao" - "Link Bolado", no qual o `Z` é maiúsculo. E a ordem dos parametros em `strstr` está correta. A função procura `str2` em `str1`. Da [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) "str1 - C string to be scanned."

Answer (score 1):

Eu vejo dois problemas: o primeiro é o tamanho do array que você definiu como:

char nome[10000]

Quando a questão diz que a entrada pode ser S(1 ≤ |S| ≤ 10^5), isto é, uma string de tamanho 1 até  100000 (cem mil), como as strings em C precisam do caracter \0 no fim do array, então você deveria definir o seu array assim:

char nome[100001]; /* tamanho maximo cem mil e um */

O outro problema é o getchar() antes do scanf(), não é necessário pois com isso você remove sempre o primeiro caracter da entrada fazendo com que uma entrada que inicie com "zelda" seja "elda" e tornando a resposta "Link Tranquilo" quando na verdade é "Link Bolado".